# Encryption and Decryption on PIC18F1320

Tags: encryption, pic

I have a pair of transceivers connected to the micro-controller from Port A, and a MM232R connected to Port B on a separate PCB. Each transceiver will send encrypted data, while MM232R will receive a decrypted data. I need write encryption algorithm and decryption code. Can anyone give me idea on how to go about it? I am new to programming and encryption algorithm.

Comment: What kind of encryption?

Comment: It is considered bad practice to do your own implementation of encryption and decryption algorithms. It is common proctice to use established libraries to do encryption. Choosing those libraries generally depends on what your platform is, what language you are programming in, and what your resouce constraints are.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the ROM/RAM limits of the PIC18F1320, that is the main constraint.

[This page](http://www.on4jx.net/microcontroller/AESonEmbedded.php?PHPSESSID=94f22495a44797a4876adf88a5beb0f3) contains an implementation of AES on a PIC18F4620. It uses 2K words of ROM and 240 bytes of RAM.

[This other page](http://edipermadi.wordpress.com/2008/07/04/implementing-rsa-public-key-cipher-on-pic18f4550/) seems to have an implementation of RSA on a PIC18F4550, but it warns that it is very slow (which does't surprise me, since RSA encryption requires modular arithmetic on large integers).